# How can I get MFC support apart from creating MFC application using App Wizard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I know that when we use App Wizard for creating an MFC application in VC++, the wizard automatically adds the required libs to the project.

I want to create an MFC application manually. How to do that?

Comment: @BROY: If I misunderstood your question, then let me know.

Comment: Sorry but apart from deeper understanding of the MFC header files and its dependencies, I don't see any other possible reason why would you want to create MFC app manually, when there is support in Visual Studio for it. If you are dealing with some specific problem, then create new question and make sure you describe it properly - otherwise I'm afraid it will be closed as not constructive or not a real question.

Comment: @LihO There are many reasons why BROY might want to create MFC app manually. Maybe his IDE is malfunctioning.

Comment: *"I want to create an MFC application manually. How to do that?"* - By adding the headers and libraries manually to your project. Seems like an obvious solution. What are you really having problems with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an MFC app manually, there are a lot of dependencies and fussing around. But it can be fun to do. Here is a small tutorial.

Create the following HelloMFC file:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

  class HelloApplication : public CWinApp
  {
  public:     
   virtual BOOL InitInstance();
  };

  HelloApplication HelloApp;

  class HelloWindow : public CFrameWnd
  {        
   CButton* m_pHelloButton;
  public:     
   HelloWindow();
  };


  BOOL HelloApplication::InitInstance()
  {        
   m_pMainWnd = new HelloWindow();       
   m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);      
   m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();      
   return TRUE;
  }


  HelloWindow::HelloWindow()
  {        
   Create(NULL,             
    "Hello World!",               
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_HSCROLL,                
    CRect(0,0,140,80));        
   m_pHelloButton = new CButton();
   m_pHelloButton->Create("Hello World!",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,CRect(20,20,120,40),this,1);
  }
```

To Compile this at the command line, there's are all the libraries that need to be linked. You will notice that there is no WinMain or main in the code above. MFC burried its main in the libraries.  It is defined in `appmodul.cpp` which you can find in your MFC\SRC directory.

Anyway, here is how you can compile the above code:

> cl.exe hellomfc.cpp /EHsc /I atlmfc\include /I Includes /I
>   Includes\Winsdk atlmfc\lib\amd64\nafxcw.lib Libs\libcmt.lib Libs\Ke
>   rnel32.Lib Libs\User32.Lib Libs\Gdi32.Lib Libs\MSImg32.Lib
>   Libs\ComDlg32.Lib Lib s\WinSpool.Lib Libs\AdvAPI32.Lib
>   Libs\Shell32.Lib Libs\ComCtl32.Lib Libs\ShLwApi .Lib Libs\Uuid.lib
>   atlmfc\lib\amd64\atls.lib Libs\Ole32.Lib Libs\OleAut32.Lib Li
>   bs\oldnames.lib Libs\WS2_32.Lib Libs\MsWSock.Lib Libs\OleAcc.Lib
>   Libs\comsuppw.l ib Libs\GdiPlus.lib Libs\Imm32.Lib Libs\WinMM.Lib
>   Libs\MsXml2.Lib Libs\OleDlg.L ib Libs\Urlmon.Lib 
>   /link/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Note: the above obviously depends on the specific location of your library files, but those are the required libraries.

Answer (score 6):

When you create a new MFC application, you will find this code in the precompiled header:

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
```

which is how the MFC header files get included. Even if you try to create a new Win32 Console Application and ask the wizard to include MFC support, you will again find these lines in the precompiled header:

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
```

So if you want to create a console application that just somehow uses the MFC classes, then just create a new empty project, go to its properties and in **General** change **Use of MFC** from *Use Standard Windows Libraries* to *Use MFC in a Static Library*. Then you just need to include these headers and you are ready to go. ;)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions

int main()
{
    CByteArray a;
    a.Add(7);
    std::cout << (int)a[0];
}
```

Comment: I found my answer.  http://www1bpt.bridgeport.edu/sed/fcourses/cs440/Lectures/cs440_lec1.doc.  (Page-11).